# What is the best approach to initialize values that are associated with enum?

Tags: c++, enums

In one class Foo i have and enum OperatorsTypes. And method that is used to Initialize values
assutiatied with that enum:

```
void InitializeOpTypesCC()
{
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::CreateChannel] = 3;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::CreateOperator] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::DeleteChannel] = 2;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Division] = 2;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Equal] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::GetOperatorContactsCount] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::GetInputOperatorId] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::GetTypeOfOperator] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::If] = 2;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::IsChannelExists] = 3;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Minus] = 2;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Multiplication] = 2;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::One] = 0;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Plus] = 2;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::RandomNumber] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::RemoveOperator] = 1;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Time] = 0;
    _operatorTypeContactCount[OperatorsTypes::Nothing] = 0;
}
```

Curently i am calling this method from constructor. But i the from profiling that 
method constructor take segnificent tyme il general timing. So i want to make this 
initialization and _operatorTypeContactCount static. To not init it for all instances.
I marked InitializeOpTypesCC and _operatorTypeContactCount with static and begin to got
linkage errors. I read about this limitaton of static. Then i moved _operatorTypeContactCount and InitializeOpTypesCC to namespace scope and mark it static . That works but i need manualy call InitializeOpTypesCC and got undefined behaviour when i forgot,     for example in unit-tests. What is the best way in this case?

This can be const static array but i need to initialize it by index, like:
 const int test[] = {
    [ind1]  = 10,
    [ind2]  = 5,
    //.
    //.
    //.
};. Not one by one like in const char Foo::array[] = { '1', '2', '3' }; That isn't convenient because enume can change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18784796/1175253

Comment: Static class member + linker error: it looks like you only declared this member as static in h-file and not created the variable in .cpp file.

Comment: Why is it you think initializing 18 variables takes a significant amount of time?

Comment: @ZacHowland I see this from profiling. I create millions and millions  of such objects... so it became essential

Comment: @BransDs And are these `_operatorTypeContractCount` variables unique to each instance of the class?

Comment: @Sam example from  C99 syntax with const array looks perfect but it don't works for me in using 11 C++. Can you you give example?

Comment: @ZacHowland no. In can be just const static array. But i know only such way of initialization: "const char foo::array[] = { '1', '2', '3' };" in cpp file... example  from C99 stackoverflow.com/q/18784796/1175253 don;t works for me in c++ 11.  i need initialization by index like there

Answer (score 1):

```
DependentType
{
    static bool staticInit = false;

    //**NOT** thread safe!! (you'd need a static sync primitive)
    if(!staticInit)
    {
        staticInit = true;
        DoStaticInit();
    }
}
```

or globally:

```
bool StaticInit()
{
    static bool staticInit = false;

    //**NOT** thread safe!! (you'd need a static sync primitive)
    if(!staticInit)
    {
        staticInit = true;
        DoStaticInit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

DependentType()
{
    //Add this to all dependent type's constructor or class body
    static const bool staticInit = StaticInit();
}
```

Even if you run that static init from another static initialization, as soon as you have static instances of `DependentType`, it depends on static initialization order, which is hard to predict and even harder to maintain.

Another way would be an adapter class with iterators and whatever needed, to wrap a static array:
[Link two enumated type members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18784796/1175253).

Comment: Thanks. But this check will have some overhead...  i think it will be better to use static member, some class, Zoo with _operatorTypeContactCount array initialization in it.